# brain is squirmin' like a toad

Tags: meaning

Please explain, what does 'squirm like a toad' mean. I've found [description](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Squirming_Like_a_Toad) which is not helpful at all -" It makes you feel simultaneously friendly towards animals and generally libidinous, which is... weird, to say the least" = friendly towards animals and libidinous in the same time???

Comment: The description you linked to is nonsense: it is either a joke or by somebody who does not understand English very well. They appear to have taken "like" to be the verb "like", which it is clearly not. Neither does the phrase suggest anything the least bit libidinous to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a phrase invented to make a rhyme. Many of Jim Morrison's lyrics don't make sense.

The original is:

*There's a killer on the road*

*His brain is squirming like a toad.*

"Riders on the Storm" from the album L.A. Woman (1971).

---

Presumably it just means, "His brain/mind is in turmoil"

Don't take song lyrics too seriously!

Answer (score 1):

It's not meant to make literal sense, "toad" was just chosen to rhyme with "road". But from the context - "There's a killer on the road" - we can infer that he's severely mentally disturbed. He's not just a cold-blooded killer who robs and murders people, there's something seriously wrong with his brain.

It's not a phrase that is widely used - if someone uses it, they're probably making an allusion to this song or using the phrase to suggest that someone's mental state is similar to that of the person in this song.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the phrase "squirming like a toad" does appear to originate from the lyrics of The Doors *Riders on the Storm*. It does actually get some usage aside from that, and I suspect many people using it don't realise that it originates there. It has no especial meaning; it is suggesting that something is squirming in the same manner that a toad squirms. I'm not sure that toads squirm that much, but Jim Morrison *et al.* needed something to rhyme with *road*, so it worked.

The explanation you linked to is not an explanation of the term at all. It's a wiki page for a computer game. It's slightly inane, and I suspect that just matches the game. The game itself is very consciously referencing the song lyrics.